# Simple PHP namespace issue

Tags: php, namespaces

Trying to implement a 3rd-party-lib with PHP 5.3.9-ZS5.6.0 and the lib uses namespaces. The code where I want to use the lib doesn't. So i have:

- facebook.php
- Mute

(Mute is the folder of the lib)

In facebook.php I try:

```
$app = new \Mute\Facebook\App();
```

Resulting in: *Fatal error: Class 'Mute\Facebook\App' not found in...*

The files are all in place.
I can say:

```
use \Mute\Facebook\App;
```

without getting any error/warning... What am I missing?

When I require the "App.php" via require_once I get the next error: *Fatal error: Interface 'Mute\Facebook\Bases\AccessToken' not found in [...]/Mute/Facebook/App.php*

Mute/Facebook/App.php:

```
<?php
namespace Mute\Facebook;

use Closure;
use Exception;
use Mute\Facebook\Bases\AccessToken;
use Mute\Facebook\Bases\Batchable;
use Mute\Facebook\Bases\Configurable;
use Mute\Facebook\Bases\Requestable;
use Mute\Facebook\Bases\RequestHandler;
use Mute\Facebook\Exception\CurlException;
use Mute\Facebook\Exception\GraphAPIException;
use Mute\Facebook\Exception\HTTPException;
use Mute\Facebook\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Mute\Facebook\Exception\OAuthSignatureException;
use Mute\Facebook\Util;

class App implements AccessToken, Batchable, Configurable, Requestable, RequestHandler
{ [...]
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code from the class definition? Namespaces are not the same as folder locations, you'll still have to include the files that declare/use the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
}
```

I created a __autoload function to "magically" require all files I need. Totally forgot about this method >.<